# Android Holo Tema no Android 8 apresentando um frame azul sobre o layout

Tags: android

Estou usando o tema Theme.Holo.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar em meu app usando IBM Mobile First, mas no Android 8 a webview está apresentando um frame azul sobre todo o layout. Isto ocorre apenas na webview e não nas outras activities e apenas no Android 8. Se alguem puder sugerir como remover este frame eu agradeço. Obrigado

Manifest:
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Lucas, nós estamos no fórum brasileiro, por favor, traduza sua pergunta e se possível coloque parte do seu código aonde está enfrentando problema

Comment: estamos no StackOverflow em Português traduza a pergunta por favor

Comment: Normalmente fica azul assim quando tem um link, será que não tem nenhuma tag <a> que não foi fechada no HTML?

Comment: Eu cheguei a testar só com o body do html mesmo, sem nada dentro e o mesmo ocorreu :/ E trocando o tema do Android por um que não seja Holo funciona normal